# Is there a jquery micro-architecture similar to cairngorm for Flex?

Tags: jquery, architecture, cairngorm

Is there a jquery micro-architecture similar to cairngorm for Flex? That helps development a lot. It makes it more disciplined, and layers out the code.

Is there a good starting point that I have to look up, before starting coding in jquery. I would like the code to be extensible and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I stumbled upon backbone.js - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Though not as full fledged as cairngorm, it is different, and interesting.

Answer (score 1):

React - https://facebook.github.io/react
Redux - http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/

The closest thing I've seen to Cairngorm is Flux.  It isn't a 1:1 mapping, but it is the closest modern JS architecture.  What I consider better, is Redux a newer take on Flux.